# Specific Flash features support on Android

Tags: android, flash, html

I have a service that uses computer webcam via Flash. Now I'd like to develop an Android optimized version of the service using HTML5 + Flash and then use some HTML5 wrapper to get an app.

I wonder if it's possible to use the same ability of Flash that provides an access to user's phone camera (frontal) on the Android (tablet pcs, smart phones). I know Android supports Flash since 2.2, but I failed to find any information on hardware access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air for Android is probably your best bet.  Its all AS3, just like your Flash code, so it should be a pretty easy transition.  Check out this link regarding the latest version of Air for Android:

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/02/adobe-air-2-6-for-android-is-now-available.html

It also includes key links for getting started and deploying Android apps built for Air.